# Add Woocommerce order notes field to cart.php & single-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

Is it possible to add the Woocommerce order notes field before the checkout form page? I would like to add it to the cart.php page and single-product.php if that's possible. It would be great if the content entered would be displayed in the checkout form so that the customer can update it if necessary.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054974/how-to-add-an-order-notes-field-in-woocommerce-cart-page/49561464#49561464